# Program displays error when user has to input the value of the random number

Tags: python, arrays, random

I have been asked to get the program to generate an array of 15 random integers and then to ask the user to input the number from the array and for it to display a message saying that it was in the array, however, I get an error instead.

```
import numpy as ny
randnums = ny.random.randint(1,101,15)

print(randnums)

target = int(input("Please pick a random number: "))

for counter in range(0,15):
  while target != randnums:
    print("This number is not in the list")
    target = int(input("Please pick a random number: "))
  else:
   if target == randnums:
      print("The number" , target , "has been found in the list.")
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 9, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: How can one number `target` be equal to an ndarray of 15 items `randnums`?

Comment: `!=` is not equals. You need `not in`

Comment: @rdas One of the numbers needs to be in the array

Comment: @JohnColeman yes, if its not equal to the target then it needs to ask the user to input the number again.

Comment: @mrKrauklis But that makes no sense. A single number will never be equal to an array of 15 numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems are the != and the == operators.
"randnums" is a list of elements. You can't compare a single value to an entire list. Instead, you want to check if the value is in the list.
You can do that by using the "in" and "not in" operators, so your code will look like this:

```
import numpy as ny
randnums = ny.random.randint(1,101,15)

print(randnums)

target = int(input("Please pick a random number: "))

for counter in range(0,15):
  while target not in randnums:
    print("This number is not in the list")
    target = int(input("Please pick a random number: "))
  else:
   if target in randnums:
      print("The number" , target , "has been found in the list.")
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is line 9 of your code as explained by the output provided.

`while target != randnums:`
This will check if the `target` variable is not equal to the randnums variable, which is a numpy array.

What you actually want is this

`while target not in randnums:`
Which will iterate over the `randnums` variable and return a boolean value dependant if the value of the `target` variable is one of the values in the `randnums` numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

Shorter version:

```
import numpy as ny

randnums = ny.random.randint(1, 101, 15)

while True:
    target = int(input('Please pick a random number: '))
    if target in randnums:
        print(f'The number {target} has been found in the list')
        break
    else:
        print('This number is not in the list')
```

Comment: It actually modifies the code... The user doesn't want an infinite loop, breaking when it gets the first match, the user just want to repeat this code 15 times